# How to show that $\sigma(n)=k$ has a finite # of solutions $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

I wish the question is clearly explained in the title. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $n\geq k>1$, $\sigma(n)\geq 1+n\geq 1+k$, so...

Comment: Much harder are $\phi$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: If $f$ is multiplicative and $\lim_{p^e \to \infty} f(p^e) = \infty$ then $f(n) = k$ has finitely many solutions. @DanBrumleve

Comment: Ah not _much_ harder then.  Effective bounds are somewhat more work though.

Comment: Yes usually to estimate the asymptotic of things involving $\phi(n)$ or $\sigma(n)$ we need the prime number theorem, and to estimate the asymptotic of the error term we need the Riemann hypothesis. Here I would try looking at $\# \{ n, \sigma(n) \le k\}$ or $\# \{ n \le x, \sigma(n) = k\}$. @DanBrumleve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $n$ divides $n$ then 
$
k=\sigma(n) \ge n.
$ 
Hence there are at most $k$ solutions.